# ng-template not supported in ngx-datatable in angular 15 version

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable, angular15, angular16

ng-template not supported in ngx-datatable in angular 15 version.... Its not working inside the ngx-datatable

```
<ngx-datatable-column [width]="50" [resizeable]="false" [sortable]="false" [draggable]="false"
    [canAutoResize]="false">
    <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <a class="text-decoration" href="javascript:void(0)" [class.datatable-icon-right]="!expanded"
            [class.datatable-icon-down]="expanded" title="Expand/Collapse Row" (click)="toggleExpandRow(row)">
        </a>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Comment: There's not much detail here, can you share the exact issue you're facing